# Jsoup CSS selector for a text node xpath

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

The HTML code is posted at the end,  i want to select the "OF" element. 
Here's the CSS selector

```
Elements position = doc.select("#content > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div:nth-child(5) > strong:nth-child(4)");

for (Element p : position) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Here's the output

```
p returns "<strong>Position:</strong>"
p.text() returns "Position:"
```

xpath from chrome when i highlight "OF":

```
//*@id="content"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[3]/text()[4]
```

HTML Code

```
<div style="font-size: 10pt; padding-left:5px;">
     <strong>Birthdate:</strong> 8/7/1991 (23 y, 6 m, 10 d) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <strong>Bats/Throws:</strong> R/R &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <strong>Height/Weight:</strong> 6-2/230 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <strong>Position:</strong> OF<br /><b>Drafted:</b> <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF#draft" style="text-decoration:none;">2009 June Amateur Draft - Round: 1, Pick: 25, Overall: 25, Team: Los Angeles Angels</a><br />
     <strong>Contract:</strong> <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF#contract" style="text-decoration:none;">$144.5M / 6 Years (2015 - 2020)</a>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 10pt; padding-left:5px;">
      <strong>Birthdate:</strong> 8/7/1991 (23 y, 6 m, 10 d) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>Bats/Throws:</strong> R/R &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>Height/Weight:</strong> 6-2/230 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>Position:</strong> OF<br /><b>Drafted:</b> <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF#draft" style="text-decoration:none;">2009 June Amateur Draft - Round: 1, Pick: 25, Overall: 25, Team: Los Angeles Angels</a><br />
      <strong>Contract:</strong> <a href="statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF#contract" style="text-decoration:none;">$144.5M / 6 Years (2015 - 2020)</a>
</div>
```

Here's the page if anyone's interested
http://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=10155&position=OF

Comment: "OF" is the fourth text node inside the div element. Unfortunately in css you cannot target a text node with a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write a css selector for a text node ("OF" is the fouth text node contained in your targeted div element).
So you will need to fetch programmatically like this (need jsoup >= 1.6.2):

```
// select container div element
Elements position = doc.select("#content > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > div:nth-child(5)");
// extract the element from the list returned
Element element = ....
// TODO will need to check that the List exists and have at least four elements here
TextNode ofNode = element.textNodes().get(4);
ofNode.text(); // this will contain "OF"
```

Comment: I have jsoup 1.8.1 and i get the following error, "the method textNodes is undefined for the type elements"

Comment: yep sorry, i was implying that... you have to extract the `Element` from the `Elements` collection you get from `doc.select` (for instance with a loop as you were doing in your sample)